# Dynamically creating a compressed Bitmap

Tags: android, memory-management, printing, bitmap, compression

I'm writing a custom printing app in Android and I'm looking for ways to save on memory. I have three basic rectangles I need to print on a full page. Currently I'm creating a base `Bitmap` the size of the page:

```
_baseBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width/_scale, height/_scale, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

The print process requests a `Rect` portion of that page. I cannot predetermine the dimensions of this Rect.

```
newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(fullPageBitmap, rect.left/_scale, rect.top/_scale, rect.width()/_scale, rect.height()/_scale);
return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(newBitmap, rect.width(), rect.height(), true);
```

Using bitmap config ARGB_8888 `_baseBitmap` is about 28MB (8.5"x11" @ 300dpi = 2250*3300*4bytes). Even at 50% scaling (used above), my image is over 7MB. Scaling any smaller than this and image quality is too poor.

I've attempted to create `_baseBitmap` using `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565`, which does greatly reduce the full image size, but then when I overlay an image (jpegs) I get funny results. The image is compressed in width, duplicated next to itself, and all the color is green.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inDither = true;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
input.close();
return myBitmap;

....

private static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, float left, float top) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp1);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, left, top, null);
    return bmp1;
}
```

I know I can compress an image of these dimensions down to a reasonable size. I've looked into `Bitmap.compress`, but for some reason beyond my understanding I'm getting the same size image back:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_baseBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 3, os);

byte[] array = os.toByteArray();
Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
```

`_baseBitmap.getAllocationByteCount()` == `newBitmap.getAllocationByteCount()`

It would be better to create it compressed than to create a large one and then compress it. Is there any way to *create* a compressed Bitmap? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

*note: Not an Android expert. I'm not necessarily familiar with the platform specific terms you may use to respond. Please be gentle.*

Comment: The 2nd parameter in `compress` is quality ranging from 1-100.  I'm not sure why you're using 3.  `compress` doesn't alter the resolution of the image, just compress the size.

Comment: 3 - random low value for high compression, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, if you have a target size in mind.

```
private static final int MAX_BYTES_IMAGE = 4194304; // 4MB

//...

ByteArrayOutputStream out;
int quality = 90;
do
{
    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, out);
    quality -= 10;
} while (out.size() > MAX_BYTES_IMAGE_FILESIZE);

out.close();
```